# Method to put in for loop to restart the loop

Tags: java, loops, linked-list

I am a student programming a card game and I am using a for loop to simulate drawing a card. My "deck" is a linked list with "card" nodes. Each "card" node has a boolean variable called "used" to indicate if the card is no longer in the deck. I want my loop to iterate until it reaches the random card, and if the random card is already removed from the deck, run the for loop again(because it will generate a different random number). Is this possible?

```
for(int i = 0; i < randomNumber.nextInt(deck.numberCards); i++){
    etc...
}
```

P.S. I realize an obvious solution would be to actually remove the node from the list, but I am curious if there is a way to do this

Comment: You need to add the code to your question.  It is not clear what you are asking us.

Comment: Why are you looping through if you know the index of the card?

Comment: @EvanKnowles `My "deck" is a linked list with "card" nodes` - there is no random access. The real question is why not use an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Card card = null;
do{
    card = deck.get(randomNumber.nextInt(deck.numberCards));
} while(!card.used);
```

Assuming, that `deck` list contains instances of `Card` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Card picked = null;
while(picked = null) { /* keep itterating */ }
```

But beware, this loop will run for a very long time once unused card count will decrease, and will fail to terminate eventually.

You d better filter used cards, and select from resulting list.

```
List<Card> unusedCards =  deck.stream()
    .filter(c -> !c.used).collect(Collectors.toList());
```